# Grandpa's crazy math. Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Grandpa says : " Bit of a stretch but--

> 2.72 = 1000 x 10000

Is he crazy or genius?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

2.72

> e = 2.718281828... ~ 2.72

1000 x 10000

> M = 1000 and C= 100 in Roman numerals so $c^2 = 10000$

Relatively speaking I think Grandpa is a genius

> $E = mc^2$

Comment: Its all relative, isnt it @Tom?

Comment: (Grumblemumblegrumblecapitalizationmattersinphysicsgrumblemumble)

Comment: @Bass, one for you: $f = \mu n$

Comment: But not in my silly riddles @Bass. LOL