# Capitalization matters in physics

Tags: science, tribond

A physics teacher saw the following in a student's work:

> $f=\mu n$ 
>    $Pa=\frac{n}{m^2}$ 
>    $T=\frac{n}{am}$

The teacher realized the student's capitalization was correct. What are these equations used for?

Comment: Did you just turn [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68939/grandpas-crazy-math-another-grandpa-mystery#comment206743_68940) into a puzzle? :)

Comment: To show the importance of Bass's comment.

Comment: The last two are 'units' equations, with time in seconds given as $N/kgms^{-2}$. Not sure how friction, pressure and time are related though...

Comment: All have "n". And the teacher said All Caps are  OK

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer:

> [They are equations for unit prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix)

Line1:

> $ f = \mu n$, $f$(femto), $\mu$(micro), $n$(nano), 
>  $f = 10^{-15}$, $\mu = 10^{-6}$, $n = 10^{-9}$, $\mu n = 10^{-15}$
>  thus, $f = \mu n$

Line 2:

> $Pa=\frac{n}{m^2}$, $P$(peta), $a$(atto), $n$(nano), $m$(milli), 
>  $Pa = 10^{15} 10^{-18} = 10^{-3}$, $\frac{n}{m^2} = \frac{10^{-9}}{(10^{-3})^2} = 10^{-3}$, thus $Pa=\frac{n}{m^2}$

Line 3:

> $T=\frac{n}{am}$, $T$(tera), $n$(nano), $a$(atto), $m$(milli),  
>  $T=10^{12}$, $\frac{n}{am} = \frac{10^{-9}}{10^{-18}10^{-3}} = 10^{12}$, thus $T=\frac{n}{am}$

Comment: Good find. Multi-line/-paragraph spoilers are a bit tricky. You have to prefix each line of the block with `>!` and you must introduce line breaks manually with the `<br />` tag ior with two or more spaces at the end of a line. But I think that the current markup with a spoiler block for each formula is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I guess it should be me to get things started with a partial answer identifying the more famous equations these are **not**:

$f=\mu n$ is not

> $F=\mu N$, the formula for [kinetic friction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friction#Kinetic_friction), where
>
>        $F$ is the magnitude of the force caused by friction
>        $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction, and
>        $N$ is the magnitude of the [normal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_force).

$Pa=\frac{n}{m^2}$ is not

> $Pa=\frac{N}{m^2}$, the definition of a [pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(unit)) (the SI unit of pressure) as being one newton per square meter.

$T=\frac{n}{am}$ is not

> $T=\frac{N}{Am}$, the definition of a [tesla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_(unit)) (the SI unit of magnetic flux density) as being one newton divided by an ampere-metre.

(In all of the above non-answers, notice how the puzzle topic has forced me to painstakingly write all the scientists' names without a capital letter, because [that's how you are supposed to do it](https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/writing-metric-units) when those names are used as units.)

The actual purpose of the equations coming up as soon as I figure them out :-)
(Probably better not to start holding your breath though..)