# Going to visit the boss?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa seemed to be in one of those crazy question asking mood again.

“So here is this guy.” Said Grandpa. He was reading a book.

> “He is in the Tesla near Edison going to visit the boss. On his way he
> might pass Langley and even see Einstein.” Continued Grandpa.

“So son, please tell me: What is on his head?”

That stumped me. Who is the boss? Why Langley?

Comment: Are you the Grandpa who is making these messy puzzles? :P

Comment: HaHa. That will remain a mystery. But messy? Seem straight forward to me like this puzzle. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68939/grandpas-crazy-math-another-grandpa-mystery

Comment: You made the puzzle, definitely it will look straight-forward to you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I kinda hope this answer is wrong for reasons that will become apparent, but perhaps on his head is

> a space helmet

because

> Tesla, Edison, Boss, Langley and Einstein are all the names of craters on the moon.

The reason I don't feel terribly satisfied with this answer is that

> they're quite a long way apart -- certainly far enough that if you were making the journey you'd do it in some sort of vehicle -- and I wouldn't have thought that going from Tesla (38N,125E) to Boss (46N,89E) you'd pass at all close to either Langley (51N,86W) or Einstein (17N,89W), nor is Tesla (38N,125E) very close to Edison (25N,99E). And I don't think you'd say "the Tesla" or "the Boss" to refer to these craters. So it may just be coincidence that all these things are crater names.

Comment: Tenaqcn vf n gevpxfgre. Xabjvat sebz uvf cerivbhf dhrfgvbaf ur znl unir znqr guvf hc. Bs pbhefr gur thl jvyy arrq n iruvpyr gb ebnz nebhaq. Gur obbx znl or fpvrapr snagnfl bs gur shgher?

Comment: I agree that this would be unsatisfying given that in the USA there are several places called Boss, Langley, Edison and Tesla and there are several monuments and statues called Einstein *something* that you could probably make it work in a smaller geographical area. However, given the head reference I suspect you may be right.

Comment: DrD's rot13ed comment above suggests that I am :-).

Comment: rot13(Hayrff ur vf va n fbeg bs cbyne yhane beovg. - V whfg fcrag n juvyr znccvat guvf sebz n frevrf bs tencuvpf. V qba'g xabj ubj hfrshy guvf vf. yby)